# How to Send Input as a List Into Function?

Tags: python

I trying to pass the input to the function but my code has a problem.

I have position with the (x, y) coordinates for each points.

I would be appreciate if someone help me to fix my program.

```
def distance(ball1,ball2):
  d=(((ball2[0]-ball1[0])**2)+((ball2[1]-ball1[1])**2))**(1/2)
  print(float(d))
ball1=[2,10]
ball2=[3,5]
distance(ball1,ball2)
```

Error has been fixed, But the output is not accurate and the result always is 1.

May you please help to fix that too? thanks

Comment: What error are you receiving?

Comment: Thank you for respond, Error: IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: `ball2[2]` is causing the issue

Comment: The code you current have return `5.0990195135927845` for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot access the third element.

Code:

```
def distance(ball1=[],ball2=[]):
  d=(((ball2[0]-ball1[0])**2)+((ball2[1]-ball1[1])**2))**(1/2)
  print(d)
ball1=[1,1]
ball2=[3,3]
distance(ball1,ball2)
```

Comment: Ok, You can use the math.sqrt and it will work.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you are accessing the third element in `ball2`, with `ball2[2]`. However, there are only two elements in the list. You need to change it to `ball2[1]-ball1[1]`:

```
def distance(ball1=[],ball2=[]):
  d=(((ball2[0]-ball1[0])**2)+((ball2[1]-ball1[1])**2))**(1/2)
  print(d)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def distance(ball1=[], ball2=[]):
    d = (((ball2[0] - ball1[0]) ** 2) + ((ball2[1] - ball2[1]) ** 2)) ** (1 / 2)
    print(d)


ball1 = [1, 1]
ball2 = [3, 3]
distance(ball1, ball2)
```

Comment: `(ball2[1] - ball2[1]) ** 2)` = `(0)**2` = `0`. isn't it ?

Comment: and I don't see any other change in your code apart from just adding spaces

Comment: @mrid this answer stands! check `ball2[1]`

Comment: (S)he went to far with indexing, so I repaired this with changed ball2[2] --> ball2[1].

Answer (score 0):

The 1 result is due to division.

In Python 2 `1/2` does integer division with `0` result.

In Python 3 `1/2` works computes to `0.5`

Just replace `1/2` with `0.5` in your code.